# Can't reconnect to TCP partner after temporary WiFi switch

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, wifi, esp32

I have the following setting:

- Laptop + ESP32 board in the same WiFi
- TCP listener on the board, connected TCP client on laptop
- I'm executing a python script on the laptop that sends some parameters to the board over TCP
- when the params arrive, the board answers with a "Okay, brb" message and closes the socket
- the board does stuff (if it's important: disconnects from the old WiFi to connect to a different WiFi where it connects via TCP to a 2nd board to do some measurements)
- the board joins the old WiFi again and tries to connect back to the laptop via a new socket to send back measure data, so this time the board is the client and the laptop is the listener

To prepare the connection on the laptop, it closes the old socket (`sock.close()`) when the "Okay, brb" message arrives and waits for new connections (`new_sock, addr = sock_server.accept()`) to then receive stuff (`new_sock.recv()`).

However when trying to do so, I get errno 113 (no route to host). 
I'm 99% sure that the python script isn't the issue, it worked with other boards before. So here's the important part of the ESP32 sketch:

```
// Connection to socket sock already happened and we just received data!

// Get the sender's IP address as string
if (source_addr.sin6_family == PF_INET) 
{
    inet_ntoa_r(((struct sockaddr_in *)&source_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str) - 1);
} 
else if (source_addr.sin6_family == PF_INET6) 
{
    inet6_ntoa_r(source_addr.sin6_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str) - 1);
}

int err = send(sock, brb_message, sizeof(brb_message), 0);
if (err < 0) 
{
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error occurred during sending: errno %d", errno);
    break;
}

shutdown(sock, 0);
closesocket(sock);

esp_wifi_disconnect();
connect_to_new_wifi_and_do_stuff();

// get back into joint WiFi
esp_wifi_disconnect();
connect_to_old_wifi();

// send back collected data via TCP
dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr_str);
dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port = htons(TCP_PORT); 
addr_family = AF_INET;
ip_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;

int sock_back =  socket(addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, ip_protocol);
if (sock_back < 0) 
{
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unable to create socket: errno %d", errno);
}
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Socket created, connecting to %s:%d", addr_str, TCP_PORT);

else
{
    err = connect(sock_back, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    while (err < 0) 
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Socket unable to connect: errno %d", errno);
        err = connect(sock_back, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Successfully connected");

    err = send(sock_back, run_id, sizeof(run_id), 0);
    if (err < 0) 
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error occurred during sending to %s: errno %d", addr_str, errno);
        break;
    }   
}
```

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong, but I really can't put my finger on it and I've tried for days. Any ideas?

Comment: "*(no route to host)*" this sound as if setting up the interface to the "old" wifi is not done completely. The system's routing table does not seem to be adjusted correctly/completely/not at all.

Comment: I've already tried putting a delay (I think 5s?) between reconnecting to the old WiFi and actually starting the TCP connection, to no change. Maybe I should try with even larger delays... or is there anything with the routing table I have to manually adjust?

Comment: wrong IP address

Comment: Oof. That may be it... I just realized that the IP string may contain the port at the end, that's of course indeed the wrong IP address.

Comment: Nope, no change unfortunately. It's connecting to the same IP than before and my laptop's IP isn't changing midways too.

Comment: The wifi router replies "no route to host" until the host with the given IP is connected. Just wait a couple of sec's and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever has the same issue - it turned out it was connected to the Windows firewall or the like. It executed flawlessly when I tried it from a Raspberry Pie instead of my laptop.